# PowerShell Where-Object - Nothing returned - I must be doing something wrong

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I run the following and receive nothing in return - I have looked in reg and validated that the displayname exists. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
$OfficeYearsToLookFor = @(
'2010',
'2013',
'2016',
'2019')

$status = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'  | 
Where-Object {(($_.DisplayName -contains 'Office') -and ($_.DisplayName -contains 'Microsoft') -and ( $OfficeYearsToLookFor -contains $_.DisplayName )) } | 
Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, UninstallString )
$status
Write-Output "Status: $status"
```

Comment: That isn't what -contains does, it only matches whole strings.  It's a common confusion point.

Comment: When I use -like '*Office*' (Asterisk before and after Office)  Still no results - I tried like for all categories and even as a single with no joy.

Comment: Are you sure you have `Where-Object displayname -like '*office*'`? Try removing your other filters to be sure it's correct. For example, with O365 installs the display name is `Office 16 Click-to-Run`

Comment: Thanks! The last thing I had added in hopes to solve it was the $status before the write-output. No change - So I posted - Now when I do the like as you suggested - It works! If I remove the last $status - No joy! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You just may be overcomplicating this use case. Just use a simple RegEx match. The `Where-Object` statement is not really needed. For example:

RegEx match to get everything that matches the string and number pattern

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*') -match '.*Microsoft.*Office.*\d{4}.*' | 
Select-Object -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion, UninstallString 
# Results
<#
DisplayName                                                        DisplayVersion   UninstallString
-----------                                                        --------------   ---------------
Microsoft Project - en-us                                          16.0.13801.20360 "C:\Program Files\...
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 - en-us                    16.0.13801.20360 "C:\Program Files\...
...
Office 16 Click-to-Run Licensing Component                         16.0.13801.20360 MsiExec.exe /...                                                                             
...
#>
```

RegEx match to get everything that matches the string and number pattern, and select only the needed properties and only lines where the year string is a match

```
((Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*') -match '.*Microsoft.*Office.*\d{4}.*' | 
Select-Object -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion, UninstallString ) -match '2010|2013|2016|2019'
# Results
<#
DisplayName                                     DisplayVersion   UninstallString
-----------                                     --------------   ---------------
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 - en-us 16.0.13801.20360 "C:\Program Files\...
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use get-package:

```
get-package *microsoft*office*201[0369]* | 
  select name,version,@{n='Uninstallstring';e={$_.metadata['uninstallstring']}}

Name                                    Version        Uninstallstring
----                                    -------        ---------------
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 16.0.4266.1001 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\Office Setup Controller\setup.exe" /uninstall PROPLUS /dll OSETUP.DLL
```